# Pronunciation in British v. American English

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, vowels, phonology

Why are words like *privacy* pronounced like /ˈpr**ɪ**v.ə.si/ in British and /ˈpr**aɪ**.və.si/ in American English (short vowel in the first case, long in the latter one)?

I read that determining whether a vowel is short or long, one must split the word in syllables, and then  if that vowel is **the only one in the syllable and is not succeded by a consonant** is long, but if that vowel is still **the only one in the syllable but is followed by a consonant in the same syllable** is short. In the case of *privacy* I think it is because of the different spellings (priv-a-cy in British and pri-va-cy in American). If so, do you know other words that have different spellings in British than in American?

Comment: The word is *spelled* the same in both languages. In *priv-a-cy*, for example, the hyphens have nothing to do with spelling. They are merely phonetic guidelines indicating syllables used (and, thereby, suggestive of pronunciation). So, you've almost answered your own question: refer to regional dictionaries.

Comment: A previous question about this topic on the ELU Stack Exchange site: [Pronunciation of “priv-” in British English and American English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/399867)

Comment: @JasonBassford: I meant "syllabled" if there is such a terminology

Answer (score 4):

As far as I remember, 'privacy' was an exception to [Trisyllabic Laxing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/265606/106592) (TSL) in American English. It was a phonological process that shortened certain tense vowels when they were followed by two or more syllables.

Privacy → /ˈpr**aɪ**.və.si/

The first syllable is stressed, has a tense vowel and is followed by two syllables, so it should, by TSL, yield:

- /ˈpr**ɪ**.və.si/ (we know that /aɪ/ gets shortened to /ɪ/)

It's true in British English whereas in American English, TSL doesn't apply.

Another exception is 'dynasty', which, in American English, is:

- /ˈd**aɪ**.nə.sti/ — TSL doesn't apply

In British English, it is:

- /d**ɪ**.nə.sti/

Comment: Some Brits do say  /ˈpraɪ.və.si/ - Lexico gives both variants for British English.  Whether it is an imported pronunciation or a survival I'm not sure.  (I have never heard a Brit say /ˈdaɪ.nə.sti/ , though.)

Comment: @rjpond: [Probably Americanisation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13044/106592).

Comment: @rjpond: And now [**/ˈdaɪ.nə.sti/** has made its way into BrE](https://youtu.be/ReiWeoAiCaU?t=44) (he says /ˈdaɪ.nə.sti/ throughout the video.)

Answer (score 2):

There are many - but lists don't make good SE questions, I'm afraid.
Basil, oregano, cigarette, Bernard, advertisement, garage, gourmet, ballet, brochure, address...

**ba**zil    **bay**zil
ori**garn**o    o**regg**ano
cigar**ette**    **cig**arette
**Ber**na'd    Bern**aard**
ad**ver**tissment  adver**tize**ment
**gar**age [or even **ga**rridge] ga**rahge**
etc

The British have a joke about it, they say that
Americans put the emph-**ah**-sis on the wrong syll-**ah**-ble.

One thing I've noticed, though never researched, is that the main differences would tend to be in 'newer' words; words that more likely came though French than early Germanic/Nordic or directly from Latin.

I also found this - [22 Words with British and American Pronunciations that may Confuse you](https://www.angmohdan.com/22-words-with-british-and-american-pronunciations-that-may-confuse-you/) - which includes a lot of even single syllable words where the pronunciation changes even if the emphasis doesn't. Too many to list here.