# Why are "south" and "southern" pronounced with different vowels?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels, phonology

I was wondering why we pronounce the vowels in the words **south** and **southern**. They seem to be very closely related to each other. Both refer to the same direction. South is a noun and Southern is an adjective, which I don't think caused them to have a different vowel.

Oxford Dictionary shows that south is /saʊθ/ and southern is /ˈsʌð(ə)n/. In short, south has a long vowel and southern has short.

Comment: Just echoing @Void’s recommendation, as the “Christ vs Christmas” answer is one of the best on Stack Exchange.

Comment: It would be the same had there been any justice in this world.

Comment: If you try to properly pronounce *southern* the way you are wondering why it is not pronounced (probably /saʊðən/ or, in America, /saʊðərn/), you may get an idea for the reason.

Comment: Also think of "pronounce" vs. "pronunciation".  In their case, the spelling changes too (*pron**ou**n...* -> *pron**u**n...*), but the second vowel *sound* has the same change as with "south" and "southern".

Comment: this question has made me think about "north" and "northern", and realise that the "th" sound is different..

Comment: @AaronF: See [this question/answers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/265658/why-dont-the-vowels-in-northern-and-eastern-get-short-like-southern) for 'north' and 'northern'. *And* the question about the 'th' sounds is completely different. I can, however, explain it if you ask it as a separate question. :)

Comment: @AravindSuresh Forcing people to speak a certain way through tyranny, rather than allowing language to develop by free choice, does not sound like justice to me.

Comment: @Void *North vs northern*: Interesting! To me, the *th* in *northern* might be voiced (rather than unvoiced, as in *North*). But, it's hard to tell because it's also a medial consonant, instead of a final consonant. That often modifies the sound as well.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

### TLDR

'South' and 'southern' have different vowels because they were affected by a phonological rule in Middle English called *Trisyllabic Laxing* (hereafter *TSL*). It was a process whereby a long vowel in a stressed syllable was shortened when it was followed by two or more syllables.

### Explanation

**Trisyllabic Laxing** was a phonological rule in Middle English (and perhaps Old English) that shortened (laxed) a long vowel<sup>1</sup> in a stressed syllable when it was followed by two or more syllables. It only applied to derived words (like *divinity* from *divine* and *-ity*) rather than underived words (like *n**i**ghtingale*). At one point, it affected all the relevant words. Later on, it ceased to be a part of English phonology, though its remnants are still highly visible in Modern English. Some examples are as follows:

- insane /ɪnˈs**eɪ**n/ → insanity /ɪnˈs**æ**n.ə.ti/
- profane /prəˈf**eɪ**n/ → profanity /prəˈf**æ**n.ə.ti/
- sincere /sɪnˈs**ɪə**/ → sincerity /sɪnˈs**ɛ**r.ə.ti/
- serene /səˈr**iː**n/ → serenity /səˈr**ɛ**n.ə.ti/
- impede /ɪmˈp**iː**d/ → /ɪmˌp**ɛ**d.ə.mənt/
- divine /dɪˈv**aɪ**n/ → divinity /dɪˈv**ɪ**n.ə.ti/
- derive /dɪˈr**aɪ**v/ → derivative /dɪˈr**ɪ**v.ə.tiv/
- pronounce /prəˈn**aʊ**ns/ → pronunciation /prəˌn**ʌ**n.siˈeɪ.ʃ(ə)n/
- provoke /prəˈv**əʊ**k/ → provocative /prəˈv**ɒ**k.ə.tɪv/
- holy /ˈh**əʊ**li/ → holiday /ˈh**ɒ**lɪdeɪ/

As you can see, there are at least two syllables after the stressed long vowels, so they got shortened because of TSL.

There's a fairly regular pattern of the vowel change in the words I mentioned above. It can be summarised as:

- /eɪ/ → /æ/
- /ɪə/ → /ɛ/
- /iː/ → /ɛ/
- /aɪ/ → /ɪ/
- /aʊ/ → /ʌ/
- /əʊ/ → /ɒ/ (AmE: /ɑ/)

In Modern English, there are many exceptions such as words ending in *-ness* (e.g. mindfulness, loneliness etc) or later borrowings such as *obese/ obesity* etc.

The above changes happen in trisyllabic (three-syllable) or polysyllabic words, but 'southern' is not even a three-syllable word, why then is it pronounced with a short vowel?

### The short vowel in 'southern'

The history of *southern* is more interesting. Wikipedia also mentions *[disyllabic laxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing#Disyllabic_laxing)* (when one syllable follows the stressed long vowel as in 'southern'), though the vowel in 'southern' is not the because of that. It *is* because of TSL.

The anomaly here is caused by historical sound changes. 'Southern' used to be a three-syllable word when Trisyllabic Laxing applied.

'South' was *sūþ* (or *sūð*)<sup>2</sup> in Old English and it was pronounced /suːθ/. While 'southern' was *sūþerne*<sup>3</sup> (or *sūðerne*) pronounced /ˈsuː.θer.ne/ ([ˈsuː.ðer.ne])

In Middle English, 'southern' was pronounced /ˈsuː.ðər.nə/. Then Trisyllabic Laxing applied to it and reduced the long vowel /uː/ to /ʊ/ (the vowel in *put*).

Then in Early Modern English, there was another sound change that caused the unrounding of the round vowel /ʊ/ in most varieties of English (exceptions being most accents of [Northern England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language_in_Northern_England)<sup>4</sup> and [Midlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language_in_England#Midlands)) and changed it to /ʌ/ (vowel in *strut*). So the round vowel of 'southern' changed to /ʌ/.

'South' was pronounced /suːθ/ until the [Great Vowel Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift#Overall_changes), which changed the /uː/ vowel to /aʊ/ (vowel in *mouth*).

---

#### Footnotes:

1. The long vowels in the base words were then diphthongised by the Great Vowel Shift in Early Modern English.
2. Both ⟨**þ**⟩ (*þorn*—[thorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter))) and ⟨**ð**⟩ ([eth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eth)) were used interchangeably to represent the *th* sounds in Old English (read [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272566/106592) for details). And ⟨**ū**⟩ represented the long U sound /**uː**/ (as in *moon*).
3. [The final e was pronounced up until late Middle English.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/463889/365490)
4. That's why most northerners rhyme *but* with *put*.

---

#### References:

- [Trisyllabic shortening in English: past and present](https://www.ling-phil.ox.ac.uk/files/trisyllabic_shortening.pdf)
- [Trisyllabic Laxing - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trisyllabic_laxing)
- [A Historical Phonology of English by Donka Minkova](https://edinburghuniversitypress.com/book-a-historical-phonology-of-english.html)
- [Sound Pattern of English by Chomsky and Halle](http://www.linguist.univ-paris-diderot.fr/%7Eedunbar/ling499b_spr12/readings/Chomsky,%20Halle%20-%201968%20-%20The%20Sound%20Pattern%20of%20English.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Void! What is meant by "diphthong" please?

Comment: @Mxtt: A diphthong is a combination of two different vowels. Like the EYE sound in 'right'; you glide from /a/ to /ɪ/. That's a diphthong.

Comment: Like many English rules, TSL also has lots and lots of exceptions, however.

Comment: Why don't "northern" and "eastern" have short vowels as "southern"? Can you also explain this? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/265658/why-dont-the-vowels-in-northern-and-eastern-get-short-like-southern

Comment: @Void Great answer!!

Comment: Absolutely incredible answer. Would give more reputation if I knew how, but there doesn't seem to be a way to start a bounty.

Comment: I'm slightly confused as to why this answer states it's not due to disyllabic but to trisyllabic laxing - "southern" has only two syllables, and this is explicitly a case of disyllabic laxing according to the reference on wikipedia provided here (the page specifies that trisyllabic laxing requires two or more subsequent syllables).

Comment: @DarrenRinger: You can say that, but D.Laxing applies to words that had historically one syllable after the tense vowel. Southern on the other hand had two syllables after the tense vowel and the linked Wikipedia article also says it's because of TSL. D.Minkova says the same about 'southern' in her *A historical phonology*. Another interesting example is 'monday' from *moon* + *day*. You could also say it's because of Disyllabic Laxing, but it was Trisyllabic (or 4 syllable word?) when Trisyllabic Laxing applied.

Comment: So pronouncing the "na" in "discriminatory" as "nuh" rather than "nae" is an example? The latter seems to be more common in BrE.

Comment: @Acccumulation: Also 'privacy'; BrE: /prɪ-/, AmE: /praɪ-/. There are many other irregular exceptions.

Comment: What were the 3 syllables in the original "southern"?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket: 'southern' was *sūþerne* and it was pronounced [ˈsuː.ðer.ne] (three syllables). In Middle English, the ending *-e* was pronounced [ə] and then lost.

Answer (score 8):

Void has an amazing and thorough answer. I would add one further point, which is that the weird patterns of the laxing make a whole lot more sense if recognize that it occurred in English before the Great Vowel Shift, which kept the short vowels sort of similar, and the utterly messed up the long vowels. In Old and Middle English, a "long vowel" was literally that, a vowel that was held longer. So the letter "e" was pronounced like "/e/" regardless of whether it was long (/e:/) or short (/e/), excepting that it was different in length.

However, after the GVS, the long /e:/ sound shifted to /i:/ (now the name of the letter). So words like serene and serenity would have been closer to /se're:n/ and /se're ni ti/. However, when the long /e:/ shifted, you ended up with /se'ri:n/ and /se're ni ti/, plus some other shifting.

Basically in summary, the "shortening" was due to slightly less emphasis placed on a vowel after two more syllables were added to it. And then the GVS came along and really messed up the pronunciation of the *long* version, making the sounds seem way more different than they originally were.

Coda:
A similar phenomenon happened with the pair wind/windmill (currently /wɪnd/ and /'wɪnd mɪl/), with an extra twist. In Middle English, the pair was /w**i**nd/ and /'w**i**nd mill/.  With the GVS, the first one became /w**ai**nd/ (the same sound you get for "wind a watch"). So you had the slightly odd pair /w**ai**nd/ and /w**ɪ**nd mɪl/. And English speakers sort of unanimously rejected that pairing some point in the later 18th century, since the words were so different.

But its legacy can be found in Shakespeare (As you like it), where the rhyme goes along with "kind":

"Blow, blow, thou winter wind (/w**ai**nd/),
Thou art not so unkind (/k**ai**nd/)"