# Why are "define" and "definition" pronounced with different vowels?

Tags: pronunciation, vowels

It just doesn't make sense.
"Define" has a long vowel and "definition" has short.
Isn't "definition" the noun form of "define"? Shouldn't both have the same vowels? Why are both pronounced differently? Can someone explain it please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are "south" and "southern" pronounced with different vowels?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/265605/why-are-south-and-southern-pronounced-with-different-vowels)

Comment: *Def**i**ne - def**i**nition, div**i**ne - div**i**nity, pron**ou**nce - pron**u**nciation, s**ou**th - s**ou**thern, der**i**ve - der**i**vative* etc., are all because of [Trisyllabic Laxing](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/265605/why-are-south-and-southern-pronounced-with-different-vowels).

Comment: "It just doesn't make sense" - welcome to English pronunciation.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because "define" ends with a silent e but "definition" does not.

Comment: Nah, it's not because of the so-called 'silent e' (cf. 'south' which doesn't have a silent e).

Comment: @Void Oops. If so, I don't know XD. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: Up to you..  But I think it's reasonable to say that 'define - definition' is because of the silent e :)

Comment: @Void So is my answer (at least partially) correct?

Comment: I'd say so......

Comment: @Void Okay, thanks! ;)