# Pronunciation rule for words like privet, private, privacy, etc

Tags: pronunciation

How to get the right pronunciation when a new word occurs for example, I would pronounce *privet* : **/'praɪ.vɪt/** like the beginning of private but unfortunately we must pronounce it : **/ˈprɪv.ɪt/**
Is there any rules?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no definitive rules, just reams of conflicting and confusing, convoluted and meandering explanations. Even this native American stumbles on occasion. Did you look at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/399867/pronunciation-of-priv-in-british-english-and-american-english

Comment: A good rule of thumb, but still not 100% accurate is if the word ends in E, pronounce the preceding vowel long. But there are exceptions. Have you tried Google translate's audio feature?

Comment: You might be interested in reading [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/272087/106592) to a question asking about the pronunciation of 'privacy' in British and American English.